# Blender Freestyle - how to make line crossings glow more than lines themselves?

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to recreate the classic, vintage 1980s look of computer graphics - bright, glowing lines on dark background. However, after analyzing old computer graphics I found out that the intersections of lines glow more than the lines themselves - they turn into little glowing points.

Is there a way to simulate this using Freestyle settings or compositor?

For example:

[image: classic CGI from the 1980s]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a blur node to get this effect.
The blurred lines will overlap a bit at the intersections, making them brighter.

For example:

1. Create a renderlayer which only renders freestyle lines by disabling everything else in *Render layers > Layer > Include*:

   [image]
2. Set the freestyle line color to white in *Render layers > Freestyle Line Style*:

   [image]
3. Composite (click for larger image):

   [image]

Result (click for html5 version):

[image]

Comment: It is a great solution, I modified it a little to have multiple colors possible (removing the final color decision from the node tree): [link](http://i.imgur.com/Dqqsg5m.png)

Comment: I achieved a similar effect by adding additional line types with an altered alpha and geometry that gets fatter at the node point.