# Highlight specific edges of a shape

Tags: vertices, wireframe

I have a semi-cylinder and I'd like to highlight the arc on the front, made of lots of vertices and smoothed. How can I highlight this? Best would be some kind of coloured glow to represent the arc.
I tried using a wireframe modifier but it seems the wireframe requires an actual shape, not just a line of vertices.
I wasn't able to add a glow to just the vertices either.

[image: Semicylinder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the vertices you want and duplicate them.  Right click to send them back to their original position.  Then press <kbd>P</kbd> and select Separate by selection.

[image]

Go back to object mode and select your new object.
If your selection has any faces, enter edit mode and delete only faces.

[image]

At this point you have a circle, or a loop, or maybe just a line of vertices.  You're now able to convert this to a curve from Object mode.

[image]

You can give this some bevel depth.

[image]

And then apply a shader.  For example, volumetric emission.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Freestyle.**

*Re question title Highlight Specific Edges of a Shape, fear it would be remiss not to throw freestyle into the ring as an option*

[image]

Created a simple  [line set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#line-set) and added the arc edges to it. Gave some thickness and a stroke color of yellow.

[How to add a freestyle stroke to a specific edge in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95051/how-to-add-a-freestyle-stroke-to-a-specific-edge-in-blender)

Then removed any other freestyle influence.

[Is it possible to deselect freestyle edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/is-it-possible-to-deselect-freestyle-edges)

[Blender Freestyle - how to make line crossings glow more than lines themselves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/blender-freestyle-how-to-make-line-crossings-glow-more-than-lines-themselves)

Comment: I tried this and only selected the edges of the arc, but it's highlighting more than I actually selected. Any ideas? https://imgur.com/a/TtHoSBv It may have something to do with using ctrl+r to make new vertices and pushing them to the edges to make the corners sharp.

Comment: Possibly. Can you select the unwanteds and "Clear Freestyle Edge" ?